# global asax application_start application begin_request methods?

Tags: iis-7, global-asax, httpapplication

I have a problem. While migrating from classic pipeline mode to integrated pipeline mode at IIS 7.0 we encounter the problem :

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Request is not available in this context...

We found solution for this problem at

```
mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx
```

As solution shortly ,in global.asax I must forward the application_start event to **Application_BeginRequest** event.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) { // sender has type 'System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory' }

Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) | {

// sender has type 'System.Web.HttpApplication' }
```

Or another solution is, Application_Start event can start later then **Application_BeginRequest** .

any suggestions ? 
I have no option like choosing "classic mode "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the code to `Application_BeginRequest` or `Session_Start`. You shouldn't use the `Request` object in `Application_Start` anyway.

The `Request` object contains information that is specific for one page request. It doesn't really make any sense to do anything with this information in the `Application_Start` event.

Comment: I have nothing with session or session_start .   
What i need is  basically calling Application_BeginRequest event before application_start event or calling begin_request method from app_start  with valid parameters..

Comment: You can't change the order of the events, the application has to start before it can handle requests. Why do you need the Request object before there is a request?

Answer (score 0):

So, change you app pool mode to classic.

Comment: this is not an option for me .